# Facebook SDK PHP doesn't work in Google-Chrome?

Tags: php, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, sdk

Ok so I downloaded the latest copy of Facebook's PHP SDK from Github, uploaded it to a test web server and ran the example that it comes with the SDK. Run the example with Google-Chrome (the latest version, and NO widget installed) and it takes me through the Facebook process but on the redirection of a successful login/connect it comes up that my session only has a single variable "state", and says I'm still not connected. I look in my installed applications on Facebook and it is definitely installed.

At first I thought there was something wrong with my session or maybe the browser, so I tried the same process in Safari, FireFox, Opera and even Internet Explorer 7. ALL WORKED PERFECTLY!!

Is there a known issue with Google-Chrome?

As for any code, I didn't change a single thing, whatever is in the latest branch of the Facebook SDK PHP Github is what I used.

Any ideas or is anyone else experiencing the same problems with Google-Chrome, its really frustrating because Google-Chrome would be my preferred browser and it means that I'm going to have to test my Facebook application on a different browser and if it goes public users of Google-Chrome aren't going to experience my application at all.

Comment: Do you get any error in your console? (talking about javascript, of course)

Comment: PHP code is browser-independent. PHP SDK works fine here on Chrome.

Comment: no errors, the ONLY variable in my session is "state" whenever Facebook redirects back to Chrome. In the other browsers theres 3 variables "userid", "access_token" and "code".

Comment: Yes the PHP is browser-independent which is why its frustrating the hell out of me, it must be something to do with the sessions or redirection that chrome is corrupting :(

Comment: I spent many hours on php SDK. On internet explorer I can login but on chrome I get constantly: "Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match."

Answer (score 2):

I beileve I was having a similar problem with IE6, place this on the very top line of the facebook.php file:

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

That may solve the problem.

---

**Edit** (adlawson)

Due to a lack of explanation of P3P header, I'll add a little more.

- The header was suggested by Facebook as a fix for apps in an iFrame run on IE6, as [described here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=452)
- The P3P header is used to simply declare the information the site uses from the client, as [described on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P)

This answer does not solve the issue in Chrome, but may be useful for problems in **IE6**

Comment: Apparently that's an issue with ALL versions of IE.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Chrome configuration in Options->Under the hood->Content settings->Cookies and make sure the "Block all third-party cookies without exception" box is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');

^^ Resolved my Chrome issue.